# How to install apt-get without a package manager

Tags: linux, package-management

How can I install apt-get on a 32-bit Linux System if I don't have an existing package manager, like yum? What do I need to get?

Comment: Could you explain what distro you are using, and what you are really trying to do?

Comment: The distro in question is chromium os. I'd like to add a package manager so I can better provide drivers to the system.

Comment: Chromeos now uses Gentoo portage to build.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` is a package manager utility for debian derived distros such as ubuntu.

`yum` is the equivalent on fedora derived distros.

**Using both of them on the same system is probably very problematic, and almost certainly pointless.**

How did you install the system in the first place?  Unless this is a very very very unusual system, chances are it already has a package manager, just you do not know what it is.